# What universal property does $\text{Hom}_R(-,R)$ represent?

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Denote by $R$-Mod the category of $R$ modules.

$R$ is described by a universal property, it is the free $R$-module on one generator. This universal property is captured by the fact that $\text{Hom}_R(R,{-})$ is naturally isomorphic to the obvious forgetful functor $U : R\text{-Mod} \to \text{Sets}$.

Is the functor $\text{Hom}_R(-,R)$ naturally isomorphic to some well known functor. If so what object does it represent?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_module

Comment: This tells me what the (enriched) functor does object wise, but I don't see how to get any natural transformation to corresponds to any well known functor $R\text{-Mod}^{op}\to \text{Sets}$

Comment: Fyi "represent" allows me to say, it is represented by the object $R$, in the sense of representable functors

Comment: @FShrike the functor $\text{Hom}_R(R,{-})$ is certainly represented by the object $R$. But I want to know if there is some other well known functor that this is naturally isomorphic to

Comment: As @AnneBauval says, this is duality: the generalization of vector space duality to $R$-modules. Duality is a pretty well known functor, so maybe that addresses the first question in your last paragraph. What does the very last question mean? "What object does it represent?"

Comment: @JohnPalmieri, thank you, I see the mistake I am making I should have asked the following. The object $R$ in $R$-Mod represents the forgetful functor from $R$-Mod $\to$ Sets. That is, $\text{Hom}_R(R,{-})$ is naturally isomorphic to the forgetful functor. What functor does $R$ corepresent; that is, what is $\text{Hom}_R({-},R)$ naturally isomorphic to?